# No message found under code... for locale en_US

Tags: java, spring, validation, message

I know... this kind of issue was already reported by other users all over the stackOverflow. Even though, I've been trying a lot of different solutions without success. I'm coding a rest microservice using spring-boot and loading my messages under the folder: "/src/main/resources"

There are three different message files in the same folder:

```
messages.properties;
messages_en_US.properties
messages_pt_BR.properties
```

My bean validation message is mapped this way:

```
@NotBlank(message = "{customer.input.password.notblank}")
@Length(max = 12,message="{customer.input.password.maxlength}")
@NotNull(message="{customer.input.password.notnull}")
@ValidPassword(message = "{customer.input.password.invalid}")
private String password;
```

My MessageSource bean is defined in my main spring boot class.

```
@Bean(name="messageSource")
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
    messageSource.setBasename("/WEB-INF/messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    return messageSource;
}
```

I've an utility class responsible to get the messages from the file:

```
package com.rumblesoftware.utils;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class PostOfficer {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "messageSource")
    private MessageSource ms;
    
    public String getMessage(String messageId) {
        return ms.getMessage(messageId,null,Locale.getDefault());
    }
}
```

finally the error message when i try an invalid password

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code '{customer.input.password.invalid}' for locale 'en_US'.
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:161) ~[spring-context-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 2):

I have finally found out what was going wrong. Actually, the code was right but the error message identifier was being passed with "{" "}" when I just had to do this way:

```
@NotBlank(message = "customer.input.password.notblank")
@Length(max = 12,message="customer.input.password.maxlength")
@NotNull(message="customer.input.password.notnull")
@ValidPassword(message = "customer.input.password.invalid")
```